# Do Hidden Houses Wild Talent feats have prerequisites?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, feat-qualifications

*Complete Psionic* lists some extra feats which market themselves as alternative versions of Wild Talent. It says that Talaire humans need to take one as their bonus feat, but it doesn't seem to say whether or not anyone *else* can take them. The regular Wild Talent feat has no prerequisites, so it would make sense in that way, but it seems somewhat unclear, since the book explicitly calls them feats, but then doesn't have the regular information for them that feats normally have.

But what seems to be implied is that, for example, despite the feat's name implying a connection to the human House Adon, a pegasus could take the Wild Talent (Adon) feat and gain all its benefits?

(The stuff about Hidden Houses starts around page 141 of *Complete Psionic*, as far as I can tell)

Comment: Could you provide a page number?

Comment: Got it! The bit about Talaire needing to take them is on 141, and the first couple feats make their appearance (to the extent that they're described) on 142. There may be additional information somewhere around there, but if so, it's in a different section.

Answer (score 1):

#### It would seem that they are racial feats, so likely not.

The text implies that Talaire are a human psionic sub race which loses the human bonus feat and gains the house version of Wild Talent instead. It would seems limited to humans solely, as it calls out half-elves as ineligible.

The rules are generally interpreted as defaulting to, "if it does not say it, you can't do it" and "you can only do exactly what the rules says, and no more".

Thus by strict interpretation, even non-house/non-Talaire humans cannot take the house feats, let alone non-human races.

---

As always, your game, your rules.
Making these feats available to other races is a minor change that should not overly affect the balance of most games.

Comment: +1. Also, making it available for other houses or regular humans may give you a hook for interesting political issues with bastards etc.